# How to determine which fields are optional, from typescript interfaces generated from GRPC proto-files?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-js

In a ts-node project, I'm generating TypeScript from gRPC proto files, where some properties are marked as optional.

However, the resulting TS interfaces have ALL properties marked as optional. And then an extra "_" prefixed property for the property that's actually optional?

What I need is just a way to check in my TS code, whether a field is optional or not (so I can skip the undefined checks etc), but I find it hard to do with this generated code.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe tweak the code generation?

(Proto version 3)

```
message GetStatusResponse {
    OperationMode mode = 1;
    optional string transactionId = 2;
    SystemState state = 3;
    string systemName = 4;
}
```

```
// Original file: proto/autofuel.proto

import type { OperationMode as _autofuel_control_OperationMode, OperationMode__Output as _autofuel_control_OperationMode__Output } from '../../autofuel/control/OperationMode';
import type { SystemState as _autofuel_control_SystemState, SystemState__Output as _autofuel_control_SystemState__Output } from '../../autofuel/control/SystemState';

export interface GetStatusResponse {
  'mode'?: (_autofuel_control_OperationMode);
  'transactionId'?: (string);
  'state'?: (_autofuel_control_SystemState);
  'systemName'?: (string);
  '_transactionId'?: "transactionId";
}

export interface GetStatusResponse__Output {
  'mode'?: (_autofuel_control_OperationMode__Output);
  'transactionId'?: (string);
  'state'?: (_autofuel_control_SystemState__Output);
  'systemName'?: (string);
}
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
export interface GetStatusResponse {
  mode: _autofuel_control_OperationMode;
  transactionId: string;
  state: _autofuel_control_SystemState;
  systemName: string;
}
```

The command I use for generating:

`proto-loader-gen-types --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js --outDir=proto/generated/ proto/*.proto`

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "machine-ui-gateway",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.8.0",
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.4",
    "async-mqtt": "^2.6.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "nodemon main.ts",
    "proto:gen": "proto-loader-gen-types --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js --outDir=proto/generated/ proto/*.proto"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the proto files proto2 or proto3? For proto3 it should work with protobuf version 3.15+

Comment: The proto file is proto3. 

I'm not sure about how to apply a newer protobuf version?

I've added my package.json to the question description.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed you are referring to types and not generated stubs.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes my problem is that all properties of the generated interfaces are optional. even though the protofile does not have the `optional` flag on them,

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and was able to partially solve it by adding the `--defaults` flag when compiling proto files to Typescript. See my more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75621525/5530965

> --objects
>
> Output default values for omitted message fields even if --defaults is
> not set [boolean] [default: false]

Unfortunately this only marks the object properties on the `__Output` interface as being mandatory. It's a start!

Comment: Thanks. But on the server side which is running .NET I guess the fields are still treated as optional, and thereby I have to risk of receiving null values in the responses, even though my TypeScript interfaces says the field is not optional - right?