# Compiled Typescript files from gRPC proto files mark every property as optional

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

I have a bunch of proto files that I compiled to Typescript with the following script:

```bash
yarn proto-loader-gen-types \
    --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js \
    --outDir=${OUT_DIR} \
    ${IN_DIR}/*.proto
```

One of the messages defined is `Bool`:

```
message Bool {
  bool state = 1;
}
```

When I look at the compiled Typescript files, ALL of the object properties are defined as optional.

```js
export interface Bool {
  'state'?: (boolean);
}

export interface Bool__Output {
  'state'?: (boolean);
}
```

I've been writing tests and when I expect `true` I seem to be getting the expected object `{ state: true }` but when I'm expecting `false`, I get an empty object `{}` instead of the object shape that I expect `{ state: false }`.

How do I compile my proto files to Typescript and make sure that non-optional properties are actually defined as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message interfaces generated by the `proto-loader-gen-types` tool are intended for use with the corresponding service interfaces, and represent objects that will be used with the corresponding runtime generated code. The "permissive" interfaces without the `__Output` suffix represent the types of objects that can be created by the user and passed to the library, and the "restrictive" interfaces with the `__Output` suffix represent the types of objects that the library will provide to the user.

All fields in "permissive" interfaces are optional because the library will accept input objects with those fields omitted, and will use the default values. By default, all fields in the "restrictive" interfaces are also optional because the library will output objects without those fields if they have their default values. The options `defaults`, `arrays`, and `objects` change that behavior for primitive fields, repeated fields, and message fields respectively.

Keep in mind that in Protobuf 3, all fields are effectively optional, in a sense. Any field can be omitted from a serialized message, and that is treated as its default value. The object representation that the `@grpc/proto-loader` library uses reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding the `--defaults` flag when compiling:

```bash
yarn proto-loader-gen-types \
    --defaults \
    --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js \
    --outDir=${OUT_DIR} \
    ${IN_DIR}/*.proto
```

And now these are my interface definitions:

```js
export interface Bool {
  'state'?: (boolean);
}

export interface Bool__Output {
  'state': (boolean);
}
```

The `Bool__Output` now has a non-optional `state` property. I still don't know how to make the `Bool` interface definition the same though. I guess for now I'll just use the `__Output` interface when typing my data.